# Rebase interactively all commits under feature branch

Tags: git, rebase

Using ref HEAD, you could select as many last commits:

`git rebase -i HEAD~2`

---

Now, let's say there are 30 commits under a feature branch: `feat/xyz`, you could easily count the number of commits and `git rebase -i HEAD~30`

Question: Is there a way to select every commits of that branch without counting them?

Comment: `git rebase -i --root`?

Comment: @CoryKramer ah ha, but that select every single commits since the beginning, say `master`. What if I only want to include commits of a particular branch, say `feat/xyz`.

Comment: Git doesn't know when a branch "started". It only knows the current head of the branch. You have to tell it which commit was the start

Comment: @JoePhillips I see, so the best possible way is via git rebase -i <SHA-1> of the first commit of a branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know which branch you branched off of (e.g. master), you can use `merge-base` to find the common ancestor.

```
git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD master)
```